# Fitting several regression models with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to fit a model for each hour(the factor variable) using dplyr, I'm getting an error, and i'm not quite sure what's wrong.

```
df.h <- data.frame( 
  hour     = factor(rep(1:24, each = 21)),
  price    = runif(504, min = -10, max = 125),
  wind     = runif(504, min = 0, max = 2500),
  temp     = runif(504, min = - 10, max = 25)  
)

df.h <- tbl_df(df.h)
df.h <- group_by(df.h, hour)

group_size(df.h) # checks out, 21 obs. for each factor variable

# different attempts:
reg.models <- do(df.h, formula = price ~ wind + temp)

reg.models <- do(df.h, .f = lm(price ~ wind + temp, data = df.h))
```

I've tried various variations, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: One coment. Why you want to do regression in groups? Maybe better approach would be using mixed model with random effect for this group variable?

Comment: The main reason is that the data is affected by at at least 3 seasonalities: hourly, weekly and a monthly effect, so to get rid of some of the varians i've split it up in 24 models. It forecasts pretty well - with very simple models, but could you link to a page with more information on what you mean and why?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**As of mid 2020** (and updated to fit `dplyr` 1.0+ as of 2022-04, updated to `dplyr` 1.1+ 2023-10-16), [tchakravarty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30015869/3250126) will fail. In order to circumvent the new approach of `broom` and `dpylr` seem to interact, the following combination of `broom::tidy`, `broom::augment` and `broom::glance` can be used. We just have to use them in conjunction with `nest_by()` and `summarize()` (previously inside `do()` and later `unnest()` the tibble).

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(42)
df.h = data.frame( 
  hour     = factor(rep(1:24, each = 21)),
  price    = runif(504, min = -10, max = 125),
  wind     = runif(504, min = 0, max = 2500),
  temp     = runif(504, min = - 10, max = 25)  
)

df.h %>%
  nest_by(hour) %>%
  mutate(mod = list(lm(price ~ wind + temp, data = data))) %>%
  reframe(tidy(mod))
# # A tibble: 72 × 6
# # Groups:   hour [24]
#    hour  term        estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#    <fct> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1  1     (Intercept) 87.4       15.8        5.55  0.0000289
# 2  1     wind        -0.0129     0.0120    -1.08  0.296    
# 3  1     temp         0.588      0.849      0.693 0.497    
# 4  2     (Intercept) 92.3       21.6        4.27  0.000466 
# 5  2     wind        -0.0227     0.0134    -1.69  0.107    
# 6  2     temp        -0.216      0.841     -0.257 0.800    
# 7  3     (Intercept) 61.1       18.6        3.29  0.00409  
# 8  3     wind         0.00471    0.0128     0.367 0.718    
# 9  3     temp         0.425      0.964      0.442 0.664    
# 10 4     (Intercept) 31.6       15.3        2.07  0.0529   

df.h %>% 
  nest_by(hour) %>%
  mutate(mod = list(lm(price ~ wind + temp, data = data))) %>% 
  reframe(augment(mod))
# # A tibble: 504 × 10
# # Groups:   hour [24]
#    hour   price  wind   temp .fitted .resid   .hat .sigma  .cooksd .std.resid
#    <fct>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
#  1 1     113.    288. -1.75     82.7  30.8  0.123    37.8 0.0359       0.877 
#  2 1     117.   2234. 18.4      69.5  47.0  0.201    36.4 0.165        1.40  
#  3 1      28.6  1438.  4.75     71.7 -43.1  0.0539   37.1 0.0265      -1.18  
#  4 1     102.    366.  9.77     88.5  13.7  0.151    38.4 0.00926      0.395 
#  5 1      76.6  2257. -4.69     55.6  21.0  0.245    38.2 0.0448       0.644 
#  6 1      60.1   633. -3.18     77.4 -17.3  0.0876   38.4 0.00749     -0.484 
#  7 1      89.4   376. -4.16     80.1   9.31 0.119    38.5 0.00314      0.264 
#  8 1       8.18 1921. 19.2      74.0 -65.9  0.173    34.4 0.261       -1.93  
#  9 1      78.7   575. -6.11     76.4   2.26 0.111    38.6 0.000170     0.0640
# 10 1      85.2   763. -0.618    77.2   7.94 0.0679   38.6 0.00117      0.219 
# # … with 494 more rows

df.h %>% 
  nest_by(hour) %>%
  mutate(mod = list(lm(price ~ wind + temp, data = data))) %>% 
  reframe(glance(mod))
# # A tibble: 24 × 13
# # Groups:   hour [24]
#    hour  r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic p.value    df logLik   AIC
#    <fct>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 1        0.0679       -0.0357  37.5     0.655   0.531     2  -104.  217.
#  2 2        0.139         0.0431  42.7     1.45    0.261     2  -107.  222.
#  3 3        0.0142       -0.0953  43.1     0.130   0.879     2  -107.  222.
#  4 4        0.0737       -0.0293  36.7     0.716   0.502     2  -104.  216.
#  5 5        0.213         0.126   37.8     2.44    0.115     2  -104.  217.
#  6 6        0.0813       -0.0208  33.5     0.796   0.466     2  -102.  212.
#  7 7        0.0607       -0.0437  40.7     0.582   0.569     2  -106.  220.
#  8 8        0.153         0.0592  36.3     1.63    0.224     2  -104.  215.
#  9 9        0.166         0.0736  36.5     1.79    0.195     2  -104.  216.
# 10 10       0.110         0.0108  40.0     1.11    0.351     2  -106.  219.
# # … with 14 more rows, and 4 more variables: BIC <dbl>, deviance <dbl>,
# #   df.residual <int>, nobs <int>
```

Credits to [Bob Muenchen's Blog](http://r4stats.com/2017/04/18/group-by-modeling-in-r-made-easy/) for inspiration on that.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just revived an old project and couldn't figured out what was going wrong! Note that your solution still fails in my R environment unless I load the `library(tidyr)` package as well. I tried editing your answer, but the review queue is full at the moment...

Comment: @Gregor thanks for the hint. I added the missing line.

Comment: The documentation says: "dplyr::do() is superseded as of dplyr 1.0.0".

Comment: Thanks @climatestudent for the hint. I updated my answer to match v1.0.0

Comment: @Gregor I advise to always load the [`tidyverse` metapackage](https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/): `library(tidyverse)`. Unless you are working on a 20 year old computer, the memory hit for loading all of the contained libraries is no problem at all.

Comment: Note that as of dplyr 1.1.0, "Returning more (or less) than 1 row per `summarise()` group was deprecated" and `reframe()` should be used instead. So, for instance, the last line of the first example solution should read `reframe(tidy(mod))` rather than `summarize(tidy(mod))'.

Comment: @C.Rea thanks for the hint. I promptly updated the answer.

Answer (score 96):

The easiest way to do this, circa May 2015 is to use [`broom`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/index.html). `broom` contains three functions that deal with complex returned objects from statistical operations by groups: `tidy` (which deals with coefficient vectors from statistical operations by groups), `glance` (which deals with summary statistics from statistical operations by groups), and `augment` (which deals with observation level results from statistical operations by groups).

Here is a demonstration of its use to extract the various results of linear regression by groups into tidy `data_frame`s.

1. **`tidy`**:

   ```
   library(dplyr)
   library(broom)

   df.h = data.frame( 
     hour     = factor(rep(1:24, each = 21)),
     price    = runif(504, min = -10, max = 125),
     wind     = runif(504, min = 0, max = 2500),
     temp     = runif(504, min = - 10, max = 25)  
   )

   dfHour = df.h %>% group_by(hour) %>%
     do(fitHour = lm(price ~ wind + temp, data = .))

   # get the coefficients by group in a tidy data_frame
   dfHourCoef = tidy(dfHour, fitHour)
   dfHourCoef
   ```

   which gives,

   ```
       Source: local data frame [72 x 6]
       Groups: hour

   hour        term     estimate   std.error  statistic     p.value
   1     1 (Intercept) 53.336069324 21.33190104  2.5002961 0.022294293
   2     1        wind -0.008475175  0.01338668 -0.6331053 0.534626575
   3     1        temp  1.180019541  0.79178607  1.4903262 0.153453756
   4     2 (Intercept) 77.737788772 23.52048754  3.3051096 0.003936651
   5     2        wind -0.008437212  0.01432521 -0.5889765 0.563196358
   6     2        temp -0.731265113  1.00109489 -0.7304653 0.474506855
   7     3 (Intercept) 38.292039924 17.55361626  2.1814331 0.042655670
   8     3        wind  0.005422492  0.01407478  0.3852630 0.704557388
   9     3        temp  0.426765270  0.83672863  0.5100402 0.616220435
   10    4 (Intercept) 30.603119492 21.05059583  1.4537888 0.163219027
   ..  ...         ...          ...         ...        ...         ...
   ```
2. **`augment`**:

   ```
    # get the predictions by group in a tidy data_frame
   dfHourPred = augment(dfHour, fitHour)
   dfHourPred
   ```

   which gives,

   ```
   Source: local data frame [504 x 11]
   Groups: hour

   hour       price      wind      temp  .fitted  .se.fit     .resid       .hat   .sigma      .cooksd .std.resid
   1     1  83.8414055   67.3780 -6.199231 45.44982 22.42649  38.391590 0.27955950 42.24400 0.1470891067  1.0663820
   2     1   0.3061628 2073.7540 15.134085 53.61916 14.10041 -53.312993 0.11051343 41.43590 0.0735584714 -1.3327207
   3     1  80.3790032  520.5949 24.711938 78.08451 20.03558   2.294497 0.22312869 43.64059 0.0003606305  0.0613746
   4     1 121.9023855 1618.0864 12.382588 54.23420 10.31293  67.668187 0.05911743 40.23212 0.0566557575  1.6447224
   5     1  -0.4039594 1542.8150 -5.544927 33.71732 14.53349 -34.121278 0.11740628 42.74697 0.0325125137 -0.8562896
   6     1  29.8269832  396.6951  6.134694 57.21307 16.04995 -27.386085 0.14318542 43.05124 0.0271028701 -0.6975290
   7     1  -7.1865483 2009.9552 -5.657871 29.62495 16.93769 -36.811497 0.15946292 42.54487 0.0566686969 -0.9466312
   8     1  -7.8548693 2447.7092 22.043029 58.60251 19.94686 -66.457379 0.22115706 39.63999 0.2983443034 -1.7753911
   9     1  94.8736726 1525.3144 24.484066 69.30044 15.93352  25.573234 0.14111563 43.12898 0.0231796755  0.6505701
   10    1  54.4643001 2473.2234 -7.656520 23.34022 21.83043  31.124076 0.26489650 42.74790 0.0879837510  0.8558507
   ..  ...         ...       ...       ...      ...      ...        ...        ...      ...          ...        ...
   ```
3. **`glance`**:

   ```
   # get the summary statistics by group in a tidy data_frame
   dfHourSumm = glance(dfHour, fitHour)
   dfHourSumm
   ```

   which gives,

   ```
   Source: local data frame [24 x 12]
   Groups: hour

   hour  r.squared adj.r.squared    sigma statistic    p.value df    logLik      AIC      BIC deviance df.residual
   1     1 0.12364561    0.02627290 42.41546 1.2698179 0.30487225  3 -106.8769 221.7538 225.9319 32383.29          18
   2     2 0.03506944   -0.07214506 36.79189 0.3270961 0.72521125  3 -103.8900 215.7799 219.9580 24365.58          18
   3     3 0.02805424   -0.07993974 39.33621 0.2597760 0.77406651  3 -105.2942 218.5884 222.7665 27852.07          18
   4     4 0.17640603    0.08489559 41.37115 1.9277147 0.17434859  3 -106.3534 220.7068 224.8849 30808.30          18
   5     5 0.12575453    0.02861615 42.27865 1.2945915 0.29833246  3 -106.8091 221.6181 225.7962 32174.72          18
   6     6 0.08114417   -0.02095092 35.80062 0.7947901 0.46690268  3 -103.3164 214.6328 218.8109 23070.31          18
   7     7 0.21339168    0.12599076 32.77309 2.4415266 0.11529934  3 -101.4609 210.9218 215.0999 19333.36          18
   8     8 0.21655629    0.12950699 40.92788 2.4877430 0.11119114  3 -106.1272 220.2543 224.4324 30151.65          18
   9     9 0.23388711    0.14876346 35.48431 2.7476160 0.09091487  3 -103.1300 214.2601 218.4381 22664.45          18
   10   10 0.18326177    0.09251307 40.77241 2.0194425 0.16171339  3 -106.0472 220.0945 224.2726 29923.01          18
   ..  ...        ...           ...      ...       ...        ... ..       ...      ...      ...      ...         ...
   ```

Comment: In R 3.2.0 with dplyr 0.4.1 and broom 0.3.6, `dfHourCoef = tidy(dfHour, fitHour)` gives me: `Error in summary.lm(x) :   length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent`

Comment: @azvoleff Not reproducible with `[1] broom_0.3.6   dplyr_0.4.1 ` & R 3.2.0.

Comment: Hmm... not reproducible here now either. Must have been an interaction with another package I had loaded - maybe something was masked.

Comment: Is there a reason why do these calls work if dfHourSumm is a data table, but not if it is a data frame?

Comment: @tchakravarty is there a way to add the vcov() for each hour in table 1?

Comment: @Juanchi Not sure what you mean by the vcov. Do you mean the standard error of regression? That is already included in the output of `glance` as the column `sigma`.

Comment: @tchakravarty Very nice answer! I have a follow up question. Let's say that we also have several test sets. How do we call the regression models of the train sets, and calculate AUC for each test set?

Comment: How do we extract the slopes from each model?

Comment: @spacedSparking, the "slopes", i.e., the coefficients are extracted using `augment` as in #2 above.

Comment: This is currently not reproducible. Getting the following errors:  `Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 
  Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.`,  
`Error in augment.data.frame(dfHour, fitHour) : 
  augment's first argument should be a model, not a data.frame`  
and `Error: There is no glance method for tibbles. Did you mean `dplyr::glimpse()`?`. Running R 4.0.2 on Linux with `broom_0.7.0` and `dplyr_1.0.1`.

Comment: @tchakravarty Same error here: `Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) :   Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct....` I think these functions have been been removed from broom in the most recent version. Does anyone have any idea how to get around it? Running R 4.0.2 on OSX with broom_0.7.0 and dplyr_1.0.1.

Answer (score 32):

In dplyr 0.4, you can do:

```
df.h %>% do(model = lm(price ~ wind + temp, data = .))
```

Comment: The documentation says: "dplyr::do() is superseded as of dplyr 1.0.0". What is the appropriate approach now?

Comment: see `group_map`, `group_modify` and `group_walk`

Answer (score 10):

from the documentation for `do`:

`.f`: a function to apply to each piece. The first unnamed argument supplied to .f will be a data frame.

So:

```
reg.models <- do(df.h, 
                 .f=function(data){
                     lm(price ~ wind + temp, data=data)
                 })
```

Probably useful to also save which hour the model was fitted for:

```
reg.models <- do(df.h, 
                 .f=function(data){
                     m <- lm(price ~ wind + temp, data=data)
                     m$hour <- unique(data$hour)
                     m
                 })
```

Answer (score 9):

I believe there's a more compact answer than [loki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63774042), which abandons the since replaced/[superseded](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/do.html?q=do) `do()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)

h.lm <- df.h %>%
      nest_by(hour) %>%
      mutate(fitHour = list(lm(price ~ wind + temp, data = data))) %>%
      summarise(tidy_out = list(tidy(fitHour)),
                glance_out = list(glance(fitHour)),
                augment_out = list(augment(fitHour))) %>%
      ungroup()

h.lm
# # A tibble: 24 x 4
#    hour  tidy_out         glance_out        augment_out
#    <fct> <list>           <list>            <list>
#  1 1     <tibble [3 × 5]> <tibble [1 × 12]> <tibble [21 × 9]>
#  2 2     <tibble [3 × 5]> <tibble [1 × 12]> <tibble [21 × 9]>
#  3 3     <tibble [3 × 5]> <tibble [1 × 12]> <tibble [21 × 9]>
#  4 4     <tibble [3 × 5]> <tibble [1 × 12]> <tibble [21 × 9]>
#  5 5     <tibble [3 × 5]> <tibble [1 × 12]> <tibble [21 × 9]>
#  6 6     <tibble [3 × 5]> <tibble [1 × 12]> <tibble [21 × 9]>
#  7 7     <tibble [3 × 5]> <tibble [1 × 12]> <tibble [21 × 9]>
#  8 8     <tibble [3 × 5]> <tibble [1 × 12]> <tibble [21 × 9]>
#  9 9     <tibble [3 × 5]> <tibble [1 × 12]> <tibble [21 × 9]>
# 10 10    <tibble [3 × 5]> <tibble [1 × 12]> <tibble [21 × 9]>
# # … with 14 more rows
```

similar to their answer, in order to access, simply unnest whichever component is desired:

```
unnest(select(h.lm, hour, tidy_out))
# # A tibble: 72 x 6
#    hour  term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
#    <fct> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1 1     (Intercept) 63.2       20.9        3.02  0.00728
#  2 1     wind        -0.00237    0.0139    -0.171 0.866
#  3 1     temp        -0.266      0.950     -0.280 0.783
#  4 2     (Intercept) 65.1       23.0        2.83  0.0111
#  5 2     wind         0.00691    0.0129     0.535 0.599
#  6 2     temp        -0.448      0.877     -0.510 0.616
#  7 3     (Intercept) 65.2       17.8        3.67  0.00175
#  8 3     wind         0.00515    0.0112     0.458 0.652
#  9 3     temp        -1.87       0.695     -2.69  0.0148
# 10 4     (Intercept) 49.7       17.6        2.83  0.0111
# # … with 62 more rows
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use `dplyr` in more proper way where you don't need to define function as in @fabians anwser.

```
results<-df.h %.% 
group_by(hour) %.% 
do(failwith(NULL, lm), formula = price ~ wind + temp)
```

or

```
results<-do(group_by(tbl_df(df.h), hour),
failwith(NULL, lm), formula = price ~ wind + temp)
```

**EDIT:**
Of course it also works without `failwith`

```
results<-df.h %.% 
    group_by(hour) %.% 
    do(lm, formula = price ~ wind + temp)


results<-do(group_by(tbl_df(df.h), hour),
lm, formula = price ~ wind + temp)
```

Comment: .. but i was faster ;)

Comment: Quick follow up - when you access the model with results[[1]] the data is from "subs", so Call.f(formula = ..1, data = subs) what does this mean? I'm having trouble using the models for forecasting.

Comment: As I understand this is `dplyr` way to write calls for grouped operations (such as lm). Maybe you could change `results[[1]]$call` to get what you want ?

Comment: By the way, if you want to predict on a model object split in this way, look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356683/apply-grouped-model-back-onto-data

Comment: This now throws an error for me: `Error: Arguments to do() must either be all named or all unnamed`.  Hadley's answer works for me so I'm guessing that this answer worked on a previous version of `dplyr` but may need updating?

Answer (score 7):

A few revisions of the tidyverse late the `do()` operator is superseded and we can fit one model per group with one line of code less.

```r
library("broom")
library("tidyverse")

df.h <- data.frame(
  hour     = factor(rep(1:24, each = 21)),
  price    = runif(504, min = -10, max = 125),
  wind     = runif(504, min = 0, max = 2500),
  temp     = runif(504, min = -10, max = 25)
)

df.h %>%
  group_by(hour) %>%
  group_modify(
    # Use `tidy`, `glance` or `augment` to extract different information from the fitted models.
    ~ tidy(lm(price ~ wind + temp, data = .))
  )
#> # A tibble: 72 × 6
#> # Groups:   hour [24]
#>    hour  term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>    <fct> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 1     (Intercept) 73.9      16.3         4.52  0.000266
#>  2 1     wind        -0.0256    0.0119     -2.15  0.0456  
#>  3 1     temp         1.72      0.861       2.00  0.0604  
#>  4 2     (Intercept) 81.5      18.4         4.42  0.000331
#>  5 2     wind        -0.0111    0.00973    -1.14  0.270   
#>  6 2     temp        -1.60      0.763      -2.09  0.0506  
#>  7 3     (Intercept) 59.9      16.1         3.73  0.00154 
#>  8 3     wind         0.00358   0.0102      0.349 0.731   
#>  9 3     temp        -1.82      0.664      -2.74  0.0134  
#> 10 4     (Intercept) 49.6      18.5         2.69  0.0151  
#> # … with 62 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

As of dplyr 1.0.0, `group_split` gives a handy shortcut for this action:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(broom)
#> Warning: package 'broom' was built under R version 4.2.2
library(purrr)
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 4.2.2
df.h <- data.frame( 
  hour     = factor(rep(1:24, each = 21)),
  price    = runif(504, min = -10, max = 125),
  wind     = runif(504, min = 0, max = 2500),
  temp     = runif(504, min = - 10, max = 25)  
)

df.g <- group_split(df.h, hour)
map_dfr(df.g, function(x) {
  tidy(lm(price ~ wind + temp, data=x)) |> 
    mutate(hour = x$hour[[1]])
  })
#> # A tibble: 72 × 6
#>    term          estimate std.error statistic  p.value hour 
#>    <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>
#>  1 (Intercept) 115.         25.4       4.53   0.000260 1    
#>  2 wind         -0.00627     0.0129   -0.487  0.632    1    
#>  3 temp         -2.57        1.26     -2.04   0.0568   1    
#>  4 (Intercept)  71.0        16.6       4.28   0.000455 2    
#>  5 wind          0.00262     0.0112    0.233  0.818    2    
#>  6 temp         -0.824       0.834    -0.989  0.336    2    
#>  7 (Intercept)  39.3        22.5       1.74   0.0984   3    
#>  8 wind          0.000342    0.0137    0.0250 0.980    3    
#>  9 temp         -0.248       0.964    -0.257  0.800    3    
#> 10 (Intercept)  56.1        21.6       2.59   0.0184   4    
#> # ℹ 62 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The code works fine but one problem is that we are losing the group column making interpretation difficult.

Comment: Edited per your comment.