# R data.table not working with dplyr do

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, lm

Following on from post:
[Fitting several regression models with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713325/fitting-several-regression-models-with-dplyr)

I came across a problem when attempting to apply this with a data.table . The problem does not exist when the data is a data.frame

Example:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

mtcarsDT <- data.table(mtcars)

lmGroups <- mtcarsDT %>% 
 group_by(cyl) %>%
 do(mod = lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .))
```

Extract coefficients of the models

```
lmGroups %>%
do(data.frame(var = names(coef(.$mod)),
            coef = coef(.$mod)))
```

Error in do_.tbl_dt(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default

```
library(broom)
lmGroups %>% tidy(mod)
```

Error in psych::describe(x, ...) : object 'mod' not found

Comment: I cannot reproduce with `dplyr` 0.5.0 and `data.table` 1.9.6, which are both currently on CRAN.

Comment: Hi Axeman, I upgraded dplyr from 0.4.3 to 0.5.0 and resolves the issue. Going to close question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded dplyr from 0.4.3 to 0.5.0 and resolves the issue. Going to close question. Thanks

Comment: To close the question, you should mark this answer as "accepted", clicking the check mark on the left of it.