# Tidy output table and stargazer

Tags: r, tidyverse, stargazer

I am running a series of regressions on subgroups (all combinations of year and group) using this fantastic method I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47112949/how-do-i-apply-the-regression-for-subgroups-within-the-population).

```
year <- rep(2014:2015, length.out = 10000)
group <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
value <- sample(10000, replace = T)
female <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
smoker <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)

dta <- data.frame(year = year, group = group, value = value, female=female, smoker = smoker)

library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(stargazer)

table <- dta %>%
  group_by(year, group) %>%
  do(tidy(lm(smoker ~ female, data = .))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This gives me a table of all possible combinations of year and group as separate model estimates. My problem is that I would like to present these regression output as separate models using stargazer. But stargazer doesn't recognize them as regression output.

```
stargazer(table, type = "text")
```

Instead of the usual regression output I get this:

```
==================================================
Statistic N Mean St. Dev. Min Pctl(25) Pctl(75) Max
===================================================
```

Is there a nifty way to feed Stargazer all the regression output in a way that it would recognize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `tidy_split` function in `dplyr` to split your dataframe based on on the groups into a list of dataframes. Once you have that list, you can use `lapply` to apply functions to each item on the list. Shown below, first fit an `lm` on each dataframe in the list, then produce the `stargazer` output.

```
# create list of dfs
table_list <- dta %>%
    group_by(year, group) %>%
    group_split()

# apply the model to each df and produce stargazer result
model_list <- lapply(table_list, function(x) lm(smoker ~ female, data = x))
stargaze_list <- lapply(model_list, stargazer, type = "text")
```

Comment: Interestingly the above code gives me 12 separate stargazer outputs. I tried this and it works ```stargazer(model_list, type="text")```.

Comment: Would you mind looking at this one as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66228661/feeding-probitmfx-output-in-a-list-to-stargazer Thank you.