# Feeding probitmfx output in a list to Stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer, modelsummary

Similarly to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66225934/tidy-output-table-and-stargazer/66227238#66227238), I am running a series of regressions on subgroups (all combinations of year and group) using tidyr.

```
year <- rep(2014:2015, length.out = 10000)
group <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
value <- sample(10000, replace = T)
female <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
smoker <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)

dta <- data.frame(year = year, group = group, value = value, female=female, smoker = smoker)

library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(stargazer)

# create list of dfs
table_list <- dta %>%
    group_by(year, group) %>%
    group_split()

# apply the model to each df and produce stargazer result
model_list <- lapply(table_list, function(x) probitmfx(smoker ~ female, data = x))
stargazer(model_list, type = "text")
```

I get an error saying

```
% Error: Unrecognized object type.
```

Anybody know how I can get around this issue?

Comment: This just means `probitmfx` objects aren't supported by `stargazer`. There's a list of supported packages starting on page 9 of the vignette: [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/vignettes/stargazer.pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/vignettes/stargazer.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Colin noted in the comments, this type of model does not appear to be supported by `stargazer`. However, it is supported out-of-the-box by the [`modelsummary` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/) (disclaimer: I am the author).

You can omit the `output` argument altogether to get a nice HTML table, or change it to save your table to LaTeX, Word, or lots of other formats.

```r
# Code from the original question
library(mfx)
library(dplyr)

year <- rep(2014:2015, length.out = 10000)
group <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
value <- sample(10000, replace = T)
female <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
smoker <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
dta <- data.frame(year = year, group = group, value = value, female=female, smoker = smoker)
table_list <- dta %>%
    group_by(year, group) %>%
    group_split()

model_list <- lapply(table_list, function(x) probitmfx(smoker ~ female, data = x))

# New code
library(modelsummary)
modelsummary(model_list, output = "markdown")
```

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 | Model 3 | Model 4 | Model 5 | Model 6 | Model 7 | Model 8 | Model 9 | Model 10 | Model 11 | Model 12 | Model 13 | Model 14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| female | 0.022 | -0.026 | -0.033 | 0.013 | -0.030 | -0.001 | -0.003 | -0.073 | 0.006 | -0.041 | 0.075 | -0.006 | -0.009 | 0.023 |
|  | (0.039) | (0.038) | (0.036) | (0.037) | (0.037) | (0.038) | (0.037) | (0.038) | (0.036) | (0.038) | (0.037) | (0.038) | (0.037) | (0.038) |
| Num.Obs. | 670 | 688 | 761 | 727 | 740 | 675 | 739 | 688 | 751 | 703 | 733 | 710 | 737 | 678 |
| AIC | 932.4 | 957.3 | 1058.1 | 1009.6 | 1029.2 | 939.7 | 1027.6 | 953.8 | 1044.9 | 977.4 | 1016.0 | 988.2 | 1025.6 | 943.5 |
| BIC | 941.4 | 966.4 | 1067.4 | 1018.8 | 1038.4 | 948.7 | 1036.8 | 962.9 | 1054.1 | 986.5 | 1025.2 | 997.4 | 1034.8 | 952.5 |
| Log.Lik. | -464.206 | -476.648 | -527.074 | -502.806 | -512.588 | -467.837 | -511.809 | -474.924 | -520.425 | -486.682 | -506.004 | -492.123 | -510.810 | -469.740 |