# Creating regression output table using modelsummary

Tags: r, modelsummary

This post is a continuation of this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66228661/feeding-probitmfx-output-in-a-list-to-stargazer/66249359#66249359). I tried to create the regression output table using `model summary` as suggested. But I run into some trouble.

```
# Code from the original question
library(mfx)
library(dplyr)

year <- rep(2014:2015, length.out = 10000)
group <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
value <- sample(10000, replace = T)
female <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
smoker <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
dta <- data.frame(year = year, group = group, value = value, female=female, smoker = smoker)
table_list <- dta %>%
  group_by(year, group) %>%
  group_split()

model_list <- lapply(table_list, function(x) probitmfx(smoker ~ female, data = x))

# New code
library(modelsummary)
tab <- modelsummary(model_list, output = 'flextable',
             stars = TRUE, 
             title = "Table x.", gof_omit = 'IC|Log|Adj')
tab
```

Question 1. This gives me a very strange looking table like this:
[image]

Question 2. Also, I would like to add a header using add_header, like you could with kable. How would I do that in modelsummary?

```
tab %>% 
  add_header(c(" " = 2, "Donations" = 4, "Crimes (person)" = 4, "Crimes (property)" = 4))%>%
  autofit()
```

Edit: Version R

```
This is the version platform   
x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.1                         
year           2019                        
month          07                          
day            05                          
svn rev        76782                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
nickname       Action of the Toes
```

Edit1:

I get the same result independent of whether I set `kable` or `flextable`. I've updated the package and restarted the computer.

Answer (score 2):

What is important to understand about `modelsummary` is that it only prepares the regression table "structure", and that it delegates the "drawing" of the table to external packages: `kableExtra`, `gt`, `flextable`, or `huxtable` (more packages to come).

This is great, because the supported table-making packages are super powerful, and they allow nearly unlimited customization. But of course, the downside is that you need to learn a bit about those packages if you want to customize. The packages in question are really well document, so please check out their websites:

- https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/
- https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/index.html
- https://gt.rstudio.com/
- https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/

Your problems seem to be:

0. I cannot reproduce the table you pasted on my computer in a fresh `R` session by just copy pasting your code. Please update your packages, restart your `R` session entirely, and try again. (What version of `R` are you on?)
1. The width of your `flextable` is too small, so `flextable` inserts line breaks. Fix by using the `width` command from the `flextable` package.
2. You are trying to add a row of labels using the `kableExtra` syntax (which is the default output format for `modelsummary`), but you manually decided to create a `flextable` output. Similar functionality is available from the `add_header_row` from the `flextable` package.

I'll use the `magrittr` pipe for readability:

```r
library(magrittr)
```

`kableExtra` solution (the default in `modelsummary`):

```r
library(kableExtra)

modelsummary(model_list) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "first" = 4, "second" = 10))
```

`flextable` solution (your prefered output format):

```r
library(flextable)

modelsummary(model_list, output = "flextable") %>%
  add_header_row(values = c("", "first", "second"),
                 colwidths = c(1, 4, 10)) %>%
  width(width = 10)
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent. I wish I could make it work. This seems to be the only package that allows me to present mfx results.

Comment: The coefficient values seem to be correct. It's just that they are repeated many many times.

Comment: The output of `sessionInfo()` would be more useful to diagnose the problem. Make sure the `modelsummary`, `flextable`, and `kableExtra` packages are loaded.