# r-squared by groups in linear regression

Tags: r, subset, linear-regression, lm

I have calculated a linear regression using all the elements of my dataset (24), and the resulting model is IP2. Now I want to know how well that single model fits (r-squared, I am not interested in the slope and intercept) for each country in my dataset. The awful way to do is (I would need to do the following 200 times)

```
Country <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
IP <- c(55,56,59,63,67,69,69,73,74,74,79,87,0,22,24,26,26,31,37,41,43,46,46,47)
IP2 <- c(46,47,49,50,53,55,53,57,60,57,58,63,0,19,20,21,22,25,26,28,29,30,31,31)
summary(lm(IP[Country=="A"] ~ IP2[Country=="A"]))
summary(lm(IP[Country=="B"] ~ IP2[Country=="B"]))
```

Is there a way of calculating both r-squared at the same time? I tried with [Linear Regression and group by in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169539/linear-regression-and-group-by-in-r) as well as some others posts ([Fitting several regression models with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713325/fitting-several-regression-models-with-dplyr)), but it did not work, and I get the same coefficients for the four groups I am working with.
Any idea on what I am doing wrong or how to solve the problem? 
Thank you

Comment: [Help others help you: provide a reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Something is a little unclear. Do you want 1) to use full a dataset to estimate one model and calculate multiple R^2 from it, or 2) to estimate the same model for each group separately and extract an R^2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options with base R:

```
sapply(unique(Country), function(cn)
  summary(lm(IP[Country == cn] ~ IP2[Country == cn]))$r.sq)
#         A         B 
# 0.9451881 0.9496636
```

and

```
c(by(data.frame(IP, IP2), Country, function(x) summary(lm(x))$r.sq))
#         A         B 
# 0.9451881 0.9496636
```

or

```
sapply(split(data.frame(IP, IP2), Country), function(x) summary(lm(x))$r.sq)
#         A         B 
# 0.9451881 0.9496636
```

Comment: Thank you @Julius. I like the second option better because the 1st option you need to run "unique(Country)" to know which country is which (if A is not the first in the list)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` function and then `mapply` to accomplish this.

- `split` takes a vector and turns it into a list with k elements where k is the distinct levels of (in this case) Country.
- `mapply` allows us to loop over multiple inputs.
- `getR2` is a simple function that takes two inputs, fits a model and then extracts the R^2 value.

Code example below

```
Country <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
IP <- c(55,56,59,63,67,69,69,73,74,74,79,87,0,22,24,26,26,31,37,41,43,46,46,47)
IP2 <- c(46,47,49,50,53,55,53,57,60,57,58,63,0,19,20,21,22,25,26,28,29,30,31,31)

ip_split = split(IP,Country)
ip2_split = split(IP2,Country)

getR2 = function(ip,ip2){
  model = lm(ip~ip2)
  return(summary(model)$r.squared)
}

r2.values = mapply(getR2,ip_split,ip2_split)

r2.values
#>         A         B 
#> 0.9451881 0.9496636
```