# Fitting models to grouped data with if else conditionals

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, broom

To ease reproducibility, I am using the `goats` data set from the [ResourceSelection](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ResourceSelection/ResourceSelection.pdf) package which has spatial data for used (`STATUS == 1`) and 'available' (`STATUS == 0`) GPS locations of mountain goats. `ID` is for individual (n = 10) and `ELEVATION`, ... ,  `TASP` are attributes of the points.

```
library(ResourceSelection)
head(goats)
  STATUS ID ELEVATION   SLOPE       ET   ASPECT       HLI      TASP
1      1  1       651 38.5216  35.3553 243.1131 0.9175926 0.9468804
2      1  1       660 39.6927  70.7107 270.0000 0.8840338 0.6986293
3      1  1       316 20.5477  50.0000 279.2110 0.7131423 0.5749115
4      1  1       334 34.0783  35.3553 266.1859 0.8643775 0.7447368
5      1  1       454 41.6187  25.0000 258.3106 0.9349181 0.8292587
6      1  1       343 28.4694 103.0776 237.0426 0.8254866 0.9756112
```

I would like to fit a `glm` to each individual grouped by `Season` (created below) but have the model structure vary according to season. I have been using a number of helpful [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713325/fitting-several-regression-models-with-dplyr) and other [resources](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) but they all fit a single model to each group where as I would like to fit different models for each `Season` grouping.

```
#Add a new `Season` field 
library(tidyverse)

goats <- goats %>% 
  mutate(Season = if_else(ID %in% 1:3, "Summer",
                          if_else(ID %in% 4:7, "Winter", "Fall")))
```

Below I create a model building function and specify the model specific to each season using `if else`.

```
SeasonalMods <- function(df) {
  #Models for Archery
  if(Season == "Summer") {
    glm(STATUS ~ SLOPE + I(SLOPE^2), data = df)
  #Models for Winter  
  } else if (Season == "Winter") {
    glm(STATUS ~ SLOPE + ASPECT + TASP, data = df)
  #Models for Fall
   } else if (Season == "Fall") {
    glm(STATUS ~ ELEVATION + SLOPE + ET + ASPECT + HLI + TASP, data = df)}
  }
```

I then try to map the function to the grouped data and create new list-columns as follows.

```
ModelFits <- goats %>%
  group_by(Season, ID) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(fits = map(data, SeasonalMods),
         tidied = map(fits, tidy),
         glanced = map(fits, glance),
         augmented = map(fits, augment))
```

Which generates the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'Season' not found
```

I am not sure how to correctly specify `Season` in the `SeasonalMods` function so that it is interpretable by `map()`.

I tried to add `df$` in front of `Season` within the `if` and `else if` statements, but this also generates an error.

Comment: Have you seen the `modelr` package? Not sure if it would help https://modelr.tidyverse.org/reference/fit_with.html

Comment: Looking more closely at your function, the `if`s inside your function don't know that `Season` is a column in `df`. You could take `Season` as an argument. Keep in mind also that `if` statements only look at the first element in a list or vector, unlike the vectorized `ifelse`

Comment: @camille `modelr` looks promising. I will look into that as well. As for the 2nd comment, yes, you are correct that I have not correctly identified `Season` but am not sure how to do so. How would I "take `Season` as an argument" as you suggest...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I'd suggested using `modelr`, I went ahead without it. Like I said above, your function `SeasonalMods` doesn't know that `Season` is a column in the data frame that it takes as an argument, so you'll get errors that it's undefined. One way to do this instead is to add a second argument to the function to take the season. Since you're nesting your data, it's easy now to pass the data and season to your modeling function. I'm using `map2` because the columns `data` and `Season` are the same length.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
```

All the internals of this function are the same—I've only added the second argument.

```r
SeasonalMods <- function(df, Season) {
  ...
}
```

Just to illustrate the `broom` functions you used, I've added the `tidied` column, and save this data frame out:

```r
models <- goats %>%
  group_by(Season, ID) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fits = map2(data, Season, ~SeasonalMods(.x, .y))) %>%
  mutate(tidied = map(fits, tidy))

head(models)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   Season    ID data                 fits      tidied          
#>   <chr>  <int> <list>               <list>    <list>          
#> 1 Summer     1 <tibble [2,106 × 7]> <S3: glm> <tibble [3 × 5]>
#> 2 Summer     2 <tibble [1,668 × 7]> <S3: glm> <tibble [3 × 5]>
#> 3 Summer     3 <tibble [1,539 × 7]> <S3: glm> <tibble [3 × 5]>
#> 4 Winter     4 <tibble [951 × 7]>   <S3: glm> <tibble [4 × 5]>
#> 5 Winter     5 <tibble [1,908 × 7]> <S3: glm> <tibble [4 × 5]>
#> 6 Winter     6 <tibble [2,184 × 7]> <S3: glm> <tibble [4 × 5]>
```

Just to check that the models got the different formulas for different seasons:

```r
models$fits[[1]]
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = STATUS ~ SLOPE + I(SLOPE^2), data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)        SLOPE   I(SLOPE^2)  
#>   -0.042618    -0.000989     0.000375  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 2105 Total (i.e. Null);  2103 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       468 
#> Residual Deviance: 337.2     AIC: 2127

models$fits[[6]]
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = STATUS ~ SLOPE + ASPECT + TASP, data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)        SLOPE       ASPECT         TASP  
#>    0.024625     0.017838    -0.001768     0.215217  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 2183 Total (i.e. Null);  2180 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       485.3 
#> Residual Deviance: 385.7     AIC: 2421
```

Comment: This is great. Am I correct that `map2` is only needed when mapping to `data` and `Season`? When creating the `tidied`, `glanced`, and `augmented` list-columns above  it seems correct to use `map`, correct?

Comment: Yup. `map2` lets you map across the data and the season. After that, the `broom` functions only need to work on the `fits` list, so `map` is fine