# How to iterate over columns with vectorization together with group_by function from dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, vectorization

As explained by [Fitting several regression models with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713325/fitting-several-regression-models-with-dplyr), we can use the `tidy` function from **broom** package to run the regression across groups. For instance, a demo code for **iris** dataset is listed below, but what if, in a simultaneous manner, we intend to loop over the multiple columns and run the regression with different dependent variables (*Sepal.Length*,*Sepal.Width*,*Petal.Length*) together with this **group_by** manipulation, how can I integrate the **(s)apply** function into such a situation and get the results for these regression models(3*3=9)?

```
library(dplyr);library(broom)
res1=iris%>%
group_by(Species)%>%
do(res=lm(Sepal.Length~Petal.Width,data=.))
tidy(res1, res)%>%
filter(term!="(Intercept)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `lme4::lmList` and `broom.mixed::tidy`. You may be able to adapt it to a pipe, but this should get you started. Here, `lmList` essentially performs the same function as `group_by` in the `dplyr` pipe, but it is easier for me to conceptualize how to pipe through several DVs using `lapply`. Good luck!!

```
library(lme4)
library(broom.mixed)

# Selecting DVs
dvs <- names(iris)[1:3]

# Making formula objects
formula_text <- paste0(dvs, "~ Petal.Width | Species")
formulas <- lapply(formula_text, formula)

# Running grouped analyses and looping through DVs
results <- lapply(formulas, function(x) {
  res <- broom.mixed::tidy(lmList(x, iris))
  res[res$terms != "(Intercept)",]
})

# Renaming and viewing results
names(results) <- formula_text
```

And, viewing the results:

```
results
$`Sepal.Length~ Petal.Width | Species`
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  group      terms       estimate   p.value std.error statistic
  <chr>      <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 setosa     Petal.Width    0.930 0.154         0.649      1.43
2 versicolor Petal.Width    1.43  0.0000629     0.346      4.12
3 virginica  Petal.Width    0.651 0.00993       0.249      2.61

$`Sepal.Width~ Petal.Width | Species`
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  group      terms       estimate    p.value std.error statistic
  <chr>      <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 setosa     Petal.Width    0.837 0.0415         0.407      2.06
2 versicolor Petal.Width    1.05  0.00000306     0.217      4.86
3 virginica  Petal.Width    0.631 0.0000855      0.156      4.04

$`Petal.Length~ Petal.Width | Species`
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  group      terms       estimate  p.value std.error statistic
  <chr>      <chr>          <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 setosa     Petal.Width    0.546 2.67e- 1     0.490      1.12
2 versicolor Petal.Width    1.87  3.84e-11     0.261      7.16
3 virginica  Petal.Width    0.647 7.55e- 4     0.188      3.44
```