# Purrr (or broom) for computing proportional test for grouped dataset (Multiple proportions test)

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

Let's say I have a data frame composed of "year" and "cognitive impairment" (1=yes, 0 = otherwise)

[image: dataset]

I want to compare the proportions each year. Thus, 2000 will be:

```
 df %>% 
  filter(year == 2000) %>% 
  {prop.test(rev(table(.$cogimp)),p = 0.5, conf.level=0.95)}
```

And I can check by:

```
prop.test(x = 3, n = 30, p = 0.5, conf.level=0.95)
```

However, it seems to me that I can make these analyses simpler by using broom or purrr.
My goal is to have a table like this one:

[image: final table]

Code is below:

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(2000, 2000, 2015, 2015, 2000, 2015, 2000, 
                              2000, 2000, 2000, 2015, 2006, 2015, 2015, 2010, 2006, 2006, 2010, 
                              2000, 2006, 2015, 2006, 2015, 2015, 2000, 2015, 2000, 2015, 2015, 
                              2010, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2000, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2015, 2015, 2006, 
                              2015, 2010, 2000, 2000, 2010, 2006, 2010, 2010, 2015, 2000, 2015, 
                              2006, 2000, 2006, 2015, 2006, 2000, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2015, 2006, 
                              2015, 2000, 2015, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2006, 
                              2015, 2015, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2015, 2006, 2006, 2010, 2006, 2000, 
                              2010, 2000, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2010, 2000, 2000, 2010, 2006, 
                              2010, 2010, 2000, 2000, 2000), cogimp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                                                                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
                                                                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
                                                                        1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                         "tbl", "data.frame"))

df %>% 
  count(year, cogimp)

df %>% 
  filter(year == 2006) %>% 
  {prop.test(rev(table(.$cogimp)),p = 0.5, conf.level=0.95)}

prop.test(x = 3, n = 30, p = 0.5, conf.level=0.95)
prop.test(x = 2, n = 19, p = 0.5, conf.level=0.95)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidy` from the broom package. Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30015869/13157536

```r
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

df <- structure(list(year = c(2000, 2000, 2015, 2015, 2000, 2015, 2000, 
                              2000, 2000, 2000, 2015, 2006, 2015, 2015, 2010, 2006, 2006, 2010, 
                              2000, 2006, 2015, 2006, 2015, 2015, 2000, 2015, 2000, 2015, 2015, 
                              2010, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2000, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2015, 2015, 2006, 
                              2015, 2010, 2000, 2000, 2010, 2006, 2010, 2010, 2015, 2000, 2015, 
                              2006, 2000, 2006, 2015, 2006, 2000, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2015, 2006, 
                              2015, 2000, 2015, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2006, 
                              2015, 2015, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2015, 2006, 2006, 2010, 2006, 2000, 
                              2010, 2000, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2010, 2000, 2000, 2010, 2006, 
                              2010, 2010, 2000, 2000, 2000), cogimp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                                                                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
                                                                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
                                                                        1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                         "tbl", "data.frame"))

df_test <- df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(cogimp = sum(cogimp), n = n()) %>%
  group_by(year, cogimp, n) %>%
  do(fitYear = prop.test(.$cogimp, .$n, p = 0.5, conf.level = 0.95))

tidy(df_test, fitYear) %>%
  select(year, cogimp, n, p.value)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   year, cogimp, n [4]
#>    year cogimp     n   p.value
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <int>     <dbl>
#> 1  2000      3    30 0.0000268
#> 2  2006      2    19 0.00132  
#> 3  2010      8    20 0.502    
#> 4  2015      3    31 0.0000163
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>